# Неверно показывается судьба ответа

Tags: дефект

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/720627/178988

> удалено после проверки 2 часа назад
>   участником insolor, Kromster, Anatol, slippyk, 0xdb, Artem Gorlachev

[image: Скриншот ответа]

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/720627/revisions

> Модератор преобразует в комментарий

[image: Скриншот истории]

А должно быть как-то так (хотя там тоже какая-то жесть в [истории](//ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/175074/revisions)):

[image: Скриншот ожидаемого сообщения]

Comment: А как верно будет?

Comment: @alexolut, дополнил.

Comment: У лампового комментария вообще обильная история удалений

Comment: @alexolut, главное, что сообщение верное :)

Comment: Может там только от первого удаления статус отображается

Comment: @alexolut, первое удаление было Николосом, но первое преобразование в комментарий - Адамом. Последнее преобразование Николосом. Показывается, что преобразован Николосом. Значит либо показывается верно, либо там ещё свалка багов))